# Don't have c_cpp_properties.json file in vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I started learning cpp in vscode a while ago. I am not getting back into it but I have no idea how to compile/run programs and every tutorial that I'm watching is saying that I have to copy and paste the path from my MinGW folder to the path in c_cpp_properties.json but within my .vscode folder I don't have that file. Instead I have three other files.

[image]

How do I add the c_cpp_properties.json file?

Comment: you don't need `c_cpp_properties.json` to compile C++, it is used for the intellisense

Answer (score 26):

> You can view the C/C++ configuration UI by running the command C/C++:
>   Edit Configurations (UI) from the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P).

From [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc).

This will add c_cpp_properties file.

Comment: Note that you have to install the Microsoft C++ extension first, otherwise the command wont appear.

Answer (score 6):

Typing  (Ctrl+Shift+P) is not sufficient.  The list of options that appears does not include "C/C++ Edit Configurations ( UI )"

It is necessary to type (Ctrl+Shift+P) then start typing "edit", when the option should appear and can then be selected.

Note that once this has been done once, the option appears immediately on later (Ctrl+Shift+P).  I suppose that this is why in so many answers and even the official vscode docs it is not mentioned that you must type edit the first time it is used.

Comment: As a complement, I had tried to add c_cpp_properties.json by edit settings->extensions->c/c++, but it wouldn't add a file for me if it don't exist and edit don't take effect. This answer help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Only for Ubuntu. I had this trouble in Ubuntu. I changed keys by few tweaks `(GNOME TWEAK TOOL)` to change language layout `ru <-> en` using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> and it broke commands in Visual Studio code.

For example, I couldn't invoke by <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> for create file `c_cpp_properties.json`. When I changed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> to other <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> - keyboard  shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> started to work properly and I could generate `c_cpp_properties.json`. Try to check your keyboard  shortcut. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> should be reserved for Visual Studio code.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please use text formatting tools for posting the question