# Can't find c_cpp_properties.json in visual studio code

Tags: json, configuration

I tried pressing CTRL+SHIFT+P and then, whenever I try to search for it I cant find it at all.

Can anyone know why its happening. I'm using vs code for student not the professional one.

Comment: did you try searching in file system, outside of vs code??

Comment: ii did . I couldnot find anying

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Don't have c\_cpp\_properties.json file in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62036568/dont-have-c-cpp-properties-json-file-in-vscode)

Comment: if I understand the docs correctly, it will be created if you customize the default settings: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference

Answer (score 0):

You could check whether you installed the "C/C++" extensions, and try again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).